# Your computer is disabled. Try again in 60 minutes

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, install, restart

I need to factory reset a MackBook Pro.

Every time I start it up it takes ages to load and then I see this:

*Your computer is disabled. Try again in 60 minutes.*

[image]

I tried to restart the Mac with `CMD + R` but it won't boot in repair mode.

Any alternative command?

Comment: Is your computer managed by a MDM?

Comment: Yes @NimeshNeema, we manages computers through JAMF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the firmware that loads the OS is trying to prevent brute force attempts to crack the password and too many wrong ones have been entered in a row. If you don’t want to [seek Apple Service](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384775/your-computer-is-disabled-try-again-in-60-minutes-firmware-password), supplying new EFI firmware may be one way forward. After days of works I found the solution [here](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/18342/laptop-disabled-after-too-many-incorrect-lock-password-entries).

Here are the steps to fix the problem using a tool called refind

1. Go [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and download the refind tool to an USB flash drive
2. Unzip the file
3. Insert a USB stick into your Mac
4. On a terminal run `diskutil list` and find your USB key (for me was `/dev/disk2`)
5. Run `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2`
6. Run `dd if=refind-flashdrive-0.11.4.img of=/dev/disk2` and in 1 minute you will have the [rEFInd Boot Manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on your USB stick
7. On another USB stick put MacOS Mojave following [this guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).
8. Now insert both USB Sticks on your Mac, fire it up and keep the button `Option` pressed down
9. Now you will see 3 things: Your Mac HD (in my case was formatted), Mac Mojave USB installer and the rEFInd Boot Manager. Click on the rEFInd Boot Manager.

[image]

10. Choose the Gparted button and follow [this guide](https://archive.org/details/creating-a-gpt-partition-table-with-gdisk-in-efi-mode) step by step in order to create a GPT Partition Table with gdisk in EFI Mode

[image]

11. Now if you are back in the rEFInd Boot Manager is time to move the cursor to the Mac Mojave installation, press `Tab` or `F2` and choose the option "Boot macOS in single user mode"
12. A terminal will open and you need to enter these commands in succession:

```
nvram -c

nvram -xp

nvram -c

nvram -c

nvram -c

nvram -c

nvram -xp
```

Yes you need to clear the nvram several times in a row! (nvram -xp just lists what is in nvram) Then type in exit and wait.

[image]

The laptop should continue booting in that command window until it switches over to the GUI window and you end up at the general OS Installer window.