# Your computer is disabled. Try again in 60 minutes. Firmware password

Tags: startup, password, firmware

I need to factory reset a 2019 Mac Mini with the T2 chip. Understood this is a big challenge.

Mini was caught in the "Your computer is disabled. Wait 60 minutes." boot loop using the guide at: [Your computer is disabled. Try again in 60 minutes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364269/your-computer-is-disabled-try-again-in-60-minutes)

I was able to successfully get out of the boot loop with both thumb drives in place, but now I am stuck at a Firmware Password login screen. We've lost this password - this is the reason for the boot loop.

Anyway around the firmware password?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the password login screen?

Comment: Thank you for your help. We thought we were completely toast, but then I find your guide (repost of earlier walk through) and had a glimmer of hope. Here's what we see now: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OHTBhQD0-B6nWA9cui2le3tdINXekx8o/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

You can contact Apple Support with the problem. If you have the receipts for the Mac Mini, they should be able to help you getting the firmware password cleared.

Depending on how the hardware was purchased, you might need to ship it in for a paid repair or arrange in person repair, but the online support from Apple Service can assist with your country specifics.

- https://locate.apple.com

Comment: Thank you for the thought. Totally legit, BUT the problem right now is all Apple stores are closed due to Covid. So we are trying some other workarounds to get it back up and running. Thanks!

Comment: You can just call Apple Support... the problem can be fixed without going to an Apple Store (for example there are none in my country).

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I truly appreciate your time.

I've called and chatted with Apple support and they say that it has to be done in person with an authorized service provider or in an Apple store. The mayor just shut down all retail, including all authorized Apple Service Providers. 

The specific number that you are calling? Thanks.

Comment: I assume you're in the US? - I'm not. Here we can send the computer in via UPS.

Comment: Got it. Yes, in the US. Thank you for that option.