# Your computer is disabled. Try again in 60 minutes | USB Drive Inquiry

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, software

re: [Your computer is disabled. Try again in 60 minutes Article](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364269/your-computer-is-disabled-try-again-in-60-minutes)

Hi -

Thank you for posting this process as I have been trying to locate the answer to this question for 2 years as I have been locked out of one of my MacBook devices.

That said in your instructions say to use a USB drive to get **rEFInd Boot Manager** on your USB stick and On another USB stick put **MacOS Mojave** following the guide.

I wanted to know ***how much space (GB/TB) needs to be on the USB in order to download these 2 program/softwares***. I'm trying to purchase two to complete the task but realize that I don't have the USB space size for completion.

Thank you for your help with this! I'm looking forward to trying it for myself.

Comment: REFind takes almost nothing, but macOS will need at least 32GB. I’d get 64GB. A 1GB for REFInd should be fine.  Why not take it to Apple with proof of purchase.  They’ll unlock it for you.

Comment: Thank you for that insight Allan. I am not sure how to wipe the internal drive actually. It's stuck on the 6 digit code screen that I can't remember. It's a 2018.

Comment: I couldn't locate my proof of purchase lost it in a move and haven't been able to recover it.

Comment: Forget the internal drive…I was mistaken thus the revised comment.

Comment: Do you remember from whom you bought it from and/or your payment method?  You can get copies of receipts.

Comment: I do not, I have so many Apple products both for my company and my personal that during that time too many moving parts for me to backtrack hence the hunt for a solution outside of Apple, as they came to no avail and we tried everything together.